# How to make installer set up of Cocoa project?

Tags: cocoa, installation, macos

I have make one application Cocoa using XCode. Now I want to make setup file of project. So other user can install this project directly in his system.

Answer (score 5):

In short, the polite way is to build your app with the Release Configuration, put it into a Disk image with Disk Utility or zip it up, then put it on a server and have people download it.

If you want a longer and more detailed answer, read Apple's [Software Distribution Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SoftwareDistribution/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000145i-CH1-DontLinkElementID_69).

Comment: broken link: I've found this one http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SoftwareDistribution4/SoftwareDistribution4.pdf